# ssh to a linux box going through 2 servers

Tags: openssh

I would like to ask for your ideas, we have a somewhat complicated network setup and I need to connect to dozens of linux boxes and sometimes need to do remote reboot on them but before I can even connect to the target linux box, I have to login to 2 servers first before being able to connect to the target linux box, to give you an example:

```
ssh to server 1  
   - usr/pwd  
     -- ssh to server 2   
          --- ssh to target linux box   
              - usr/pwd   
              - sudo reboot
```

Is there a way to circumvent this way?

Answer (score 2):

In newer openssh clients you have an `ProxyJump` option.

```
     -J [user@]host[:port]
         Connect to the target host by first making a ssh connection to the jump host and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate destination from there.
         Multiple jump hops may be specified separated by comma characters.  This is a shortcut to specify a ProxyJump configuration directive.
```

In .ssh/config it looks like that:

```
Host targetbox
    ProxyJump server1,server2
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, ill do more research on that on, im using a macbook to connect to multiple linux boxes.